# Instagram Graph API. Content Publishing. Publishing Videos

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, instagram, instagram-api

I can't find correct video .mp4 format what will be support by Instagram.
Any body did something like this?
.Supported [Video Requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/media).

I tried .mp4 ratio
1:1, 4:5, 16:9 in response Unsupported format.

What is means? container for video? Help please

```
Container: MOV or MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14), no edit lists, moov atom at the front of the file.
```

Post video not works.
[post video to Instagram](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing#publish-videos)

1.Use the POST /{ig-user-id}/media endpoint to create a media object container, then(Good)

```
POST graph.facebook.com/17841407853399454/media?media_type=VIDEO&video_url=https://104.131.59.122/uploads/my_images/gallery_429/im_295_1617796300.mp4
```

> {
> "id": "17901610240810878"
> }

2.Use the POST /{ig-user-id}/media_publish endpoint to publish that container(Error)

```
POST graph.facebook.com/17841407853399454/media_publish?creation_id=17901610240810878


"error": {
"message": "The video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 352,
"error_subcode": 2207026,
"is_transient": false,
"error_user_title": "Unsupported format",
"error_user_msg": "The video format is not supported. Please check the specs for the supported streams format",
"fbtrace_id": "AKJfxH9pUFixA8vGyalKw8z"
```

Comment: My browser refuses to load `https://104.131.59.122/uploads/my_images/gallery_429/im_295_1617796300.mp4`, because of the untrusted certificate – and I don’t see any reason, why Facebook should be any more lenient regarding this.

Comment: Thanks. But image I did in the same way. No problems

Comment: So what happens when you try with the HTTP version of that URL?

Comment: the second endpoint not works. 2.Use the POST /{ig-user-id}/media_publish endpoint to publish that container(Error)

Comment: `The video file you selected is in a format that we don't support` seems pretty self-explanatory. Did you do as it suggests and check the list of supported formats?

Comment: I checked no results. Probably specific video codec needs. I tried.mp4 h264 codec

Comment: Also since we can't see your code for how you created the request, it's unclear whether you're actually definitely sending the file correctly. Have you verified that at all?

Comment: Plus there are a lot of other requirements there apart from just the codec and container. We have no idea if your file meets all of those requirements. Facebook seems to think it doesn't. Unless you somehow sent the file incorrectly (so that it was blank, or truncated, or something like that), we can't really help you with that - we're not video editors.

Comment: @CBroe you was right. My server did not have a certificate. If you want can write answer and I will approve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My browser refuses to load `https://104.131.59.122/uploads/my_images/gallery_429/im_295_1617796300.mp4`, because of the untrusted certificate.

Facebook is strict about proper SSL as well, so you will either have to use a plain HTTP URL, or make your SSL setup use a valid certificate, issued/backed by a trusted authority.